# Operations on Java 8 Optional* values.

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8 has a number of Optional classes, like `OptionalDouble`, `OptionalInt`, `OptionalLong`.

Is there a nice way of operating with Optional values of the same kind? That is, I'd like to be able to do:

```
OptionalDouble d1 = OptionalDouble.of(1.);
OptionalDouble d2 = OptionalDouble.of(2.);
OptionalDouble d3 = OptionalDouble.of(3.);

OptionalDouble result = d1.add(d2).multiply(d3);
```

And of course if any of them are "empty" the result should be empty. After googling around a bit I found a few code samples where people are using those functions (e.g. `add`) but it's not the part of the API (anymore?).

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of `Optional` is to represent a function's [return value that might be absent](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-September/005952.html).

The point of having primitive specializations of streams is to avoid boxing/unboxing overhead. With `OptionalInt` and friends there's an unavoidable level of boxing (which would be worse if they didn't exist, as the alternative would be `Optional<Integer>`), but the intent is for whoever processes the return value to unbox it immediately (or provide a default or throw an exception if it's absent) and then deal with actual primitives from then on.

Supporting all the additional APIs to do arithmetic, comparisons etc. on optional primitives would add even more API bloat. Using it would lead to cluttered, slow code, quite a disadvantage compared to the perfectly fine arithmetic expression syntax that already exists in Java. In short, adding a bunch of operations on optional primitives wasn't considered useful.

Answer (score 4):

Weird. The reference [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) has a [`map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method which you could use do something similar to what you want, but it appears to be absent from the primitive optionals. I believe your only recourse currently is to use `OptionalDouble::isPresent` or `OptionalDouble::ifPresent`.

Or you could define your own helper `add` methods or define your own `OptionalDouble` class to include those methods.

Comment: `Optional#Map` appears to need a `Function`, not a `BinaryOperator`, so it would only work with functions that operate on one value, not things like `add` or `multiply`.

Comment: I've been using a helper method but I don't really understand the reason why they omitted these methods, or at least the ability to add them. Notice that the `Optional` classes for primitives like `OptionalDouble` are `final` so they can't even be extended.

Comment: @siki They are final because optionals are immutable classes and hence should never be extended, as you cannot guarantee immutability anymore then if a method takes an `OptionalDouble` as parameter.

Comment: @ajb I said something similar. IE: `Optional<Double> opt = ...; opt = opt.map(d -> d * 2);`

Comment: @siki They can't be extended, but you could make your own separate implementation and provide methods to convert from one to the other. It's not the cleanest of solutions, but it would work.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your own implementation that encapsulates an `OptionalDouble`, a very important thing here to consider is that your encapsulating class should be immutable to prevent confusion as `OptionalDouble` itself is immutable.

An own implementation is preferred over static method for readability.

I went ahead and created my own, with the most basic behaviour as possible:

```
public class OptionalDoubleImproved {
    private static final OptionalDoubleImproved EMPTY = OptionalDoubleImproved.of(OptionalDouble.empty());

    private final OptionalDouble optionalDouble;

    private OptionalDoubleImproved(final OptionalDouble optionalDouble) {
        this.optionalDouble = Objects.requireNonNull(optionalDouble);
    }

    public static OptionalDoubleImproved of(final OptionalDouble optionalDouble) {
        return new OptionalDoubleImproved(optionalDouble);
    }

    public OptionalDoubleImproved applyFunction(final DoubleBinaryOperator operator, final OptionalDouble operand) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(operator);
        Objects.requireNonNull(operand);
        if (!optionalDouble.isPresent() || !operand.isPresent()) {
            return EMPTY;
        }
        return OptionalDoubleImproved.of(OptionalDouble.of(operator.applyAsDouble(optionalDouble.getAsDouble(), operand.getAsDouble())));
    }

    public OptionalDouble get() {
        return optionalDouble;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.optionalDouble);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final OptionalDoubleImproved other = (OptionalDoubleImproved) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.optionalDouble, other.optionalDouble)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OptionalDoubleImproved[" + optionalDouble + "]";
    }
}
```

Which can then be used as:

```
OptionalDouble d1 = OptionalDouble.of(1.);
OptionalDouble d2 = OptionalDouble.of(2.);
OptionalDouble d3 = OptionalDouble.of(3.);

OptionalDouble result = OptionalDoubleImproved.of(d1)
        .applyFunction((a, b) -> a + b, d2)
        .applyFunction((a, b) -> a * b, d3)
        .get();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use plain `double`

```
double d1 = 1, d2 = 2, d3 = 3;
if (condition)
    d1 = Double.NaN;
double result = (d1 + d2) * d3; // if any double is NaN, the result is NaN
```

Not only is the faster and shorter, it is also simpler.