# Can I not map/flatMap an OptionalInt?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Why does there seem to be no `map()`/`flatMap()` methods on OptionalInt or other primitive optional flavors?

The `stream()` map operations allow conversion between objects and primitives. But why does Optional not exploit this?

```
OptionalInt profileId = OptionalInt.of(124);

Optional<Profile> profile = profileId.map(i -> getProfile(i));  //no such valid map() method!
```

Comment: For whatever reason, they decided not to include those operations in the primitive flavors of Optional.

Comment: But what would stop from implementing a method that converts over an OptionalInt to an Optional? Stream does something similar I imagine.

Comment: Maybe it was left out to keep it lightweight since that is the point of primitives? There would have to be several variants of map and flatmap methods to accommodate the other primitive optional flavors as well as the standard object Optional.

Comment: The return value of  `map` would be another kind of optional, not a `Profile` wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't know the rationale but you can just wrap your `OptionalInt` in an `Optional`: `Profile profile = Optional.of(profileId).filter(OptionalInt::isPresent).map(opt -> getProfile(opt.getAsInt())).orElseThrow(...);`. Otherwise use an `Optional<Integer>`.

Comment: Oh good point... I'll update my sample code.

Comment: Ah I see what you did there. Very clever. You wrapped another Optional around the OptionalInt and filtered for its presence. That's actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operations on Java 8 Optional\* values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414903/operations-on-java-8-optional-values)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primitive optionals haven't *map*, *flatMap* and *filter* methods by design.

Moreover, according to [Java8 in Action p.305](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291994) you shouldn't use them.
The justification of use primitive on streams are the performance reasons. In case of huge number of elements, boxing/unboxing overhead is significant. But this is senselessly since there is only one element in Optional.

Besides, consider example:

```
public class Foo {
    public Optional<Integer> someMethod() {
        return Optional.of(42);
    }
}
```

And usage as method reference:

```
.stream()
.map(Foo::someMethod)
```

If you change return type of someMethod to **OptionalInt**:

```
public OptionalInt someMethod() {
    return OptionalInt.of(42);
}
```

You cannot use it as method reference and code will not compile on:

```
.map(Foo::someMethod)
```

Comment: I don't see the point of your example. with `someMethod` returning `OptionalInt`, you can map it, it will transform a `Stream<Foo>` into a `Stream<OptionalInt>` (as opposed to a `Stream<Optional<Integer>>` in the first case). And the performance argument does not hold either. The operations on `Stream` and `Optional` are also about composition. I can `stream.reduce(binOp).map(fun)` on a `Stream`, but I cannot do it on an `IntStream`. The lack of consistency is annoying. At least there could have been a `Optional<Integer> boxed()` as there is on `IntStream`...

Comment: maybe 'map' from one OptionalInt to another isn't that useful.  But 'mapToObject' is.   `OptionalInt x = ...;  x.mapToObject(Integer::toString).orElse("");` would be useful.  Or any number of other cases where you want to take an OptionalInt into an Option<A>

Comment: "you shouldn't use them" but the Java API has methods that return them, like IntStream.max()

Comment: "you shouldn't use them" isn't convincing to me. To cite another book, Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, 3rd edition says in item 55:

"... you should never return an optional of a boxed primitive type, with the possible exception of the minor primitive types, Boolean, Byte, Character, Short, and Float"

Answer (score 8):

It seems in Java 9 [`OptionalInt`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/index.html?java/util/OptionalInt.html) will have a `stream` method that gives you an `IntStream` with either 0 or 1 element in it. On this stream you can of course use `map()`, `flatMap()` or `filter()`, etc.

For Java 8 I have nothing to add to [user2138356’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29113582/5772882).