# Why is there no mapToInt() in the OptionalInt class?

Tags: java, java-8

The `IntStream` class has `map()`, `mapToObj()`, `mapToLong()` and `mapToDouble()` methods, but those methods seem to be missing from the `OptionalInt` class.

Is there a good reason for those methods to be missing?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask why `OptionalInt` doesn't have `map` and `flatMap` as `Optional` does.

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the why (and I guess we'will have to wait a member of the dev team to have the answer), Java 9 will introduce a `stream()` method on Optionals. So you could do `Optional<T> optObj = myOptInt.stream().mapToObj(..).findFirst();` as a workaround.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104968/can-i-not-map-flatmap-an-optionalint

Comment: You get an `OptionalInt` mostly from `min` &co.  So instead of `.min () .stream () .boxed () .map ()` you could say `.boxed () .min () .map ()`.  This is still clumsy but a bit less clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Rather obtusely you can do

```
OptionalInt oi = OptionalInt.of(1);
oi.ifPresent(i -> IntStream.of(i).map(j -> j + 1).forEach(System.out::println));
```

However it is not clear why `OptionalInt` doesn't have the same methods as `IntStream` although I note `Optional` has a subset of `Stream`