# Why there isn't map() on those Primitive Optional?

Tags: java, option-type, primitive

I just found that `OptionalInt` and `OptionalLong` don't have `map()`.

```
OptionalLong some() {
}

Optional<Something> doWithSome() {
    some()
    .map(find Something with the value)
    .orElseGet(() -> Optional.of(new Something()));
}
```

Why?

Comment: See also [Can I not map/flatMap an OptionalInt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104968/can-i-not-map-flatmap-an-optionalint)